# Difficulty removing Outer Tie Rod from steering knuckle

Tags: steering, acura, integra, tie-rod

On my '95 Acura Integra LS, the driver's side outer tie rod is embedded in the steering knuckle. I am unable to loosen the jam-nut.

How do I remove the outer tie rod from the steering knuckle?

This photo shows that upward force applied by jack is insufficient to remove the outer tie rod. (The vehicle has been properly secured on jack stands.)

[image: The upward force applied by jack is insufficient to remove the outer tie rod.]

Follow-up: [How to unscrew inner and outer tie rods?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38113/outer-tie-rod-removal/38114#38114)

Comment: Before you loosen the gym not put some electrical tape at its base so you know where to reposition it so you don't have to redo your alignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a BFH (Big F-ING Hammer), hit the steering knuckle right on the end, directly in line with the arm. Leave the jack in place and don't be afraid of it. Hit it like you mean it. The tie rod end should pop free of the knuckle arm in two or three whacks. The principle here is, the vibration from the hit travels through the arm and dislodges the tie Rod end. Works like a charm every time. Just ensure you protect the threads of the tie rod end so as not to damage them. This is half the reason for leaving the jack in place.

Comment: Does this work if I can not loosen the jam not first?  I am interpreting the technique to look like this: https://youtu.be/5MJOtr-vj6M?t=54s

Comment: You are trying to separate the rod from the arm, right? If so, then this will work just fine. I don't see the castle but on the tie rod, so it shouldn't be an issue. If by "jam nut" you are talking about where the tie rod end attaches to the rack, then use two wrenches, one on the tie rod and one on the jam nut, twisting them counter to each other.

Comment: Your help is appreciated.  I am trying to separate the outer tie rod at the point where the jack is applying upward force (castle nut was removed).   Jam-nut as defined shown in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MJOtr-vj6M&feature=youtu.be&t=39s    Do I need to loosen the jam-nut in order for the BFH to work its magic?

Comment: Nope. Just hammer the arm as described and you should be golden. Ensure you don't hit the tie rod itself, just the knuckle arm.

Comment: Success!  I had to hit it as hard as possible.  Thanks for the guidance \ nudge.

Answer (score 2):

Using a proper ball joint separator makes this much easier - either a pickle fork (basically a wedge that you hammer in):

[image]

or threaded-type:

[image: ball joint separator]

Comment: I'm not a fan of using these if I plan on re-using the component (tie-rod or ball-joint), as these tend to destroy the boot. I'd only use these if I'm replacing the component in question.

Comment: @Shamtam https://www.amazon.com/OTC-6296-Pitman-Arm-Puller/dp/B000KITTYU work without destroying the boot. Or like paulster2 said just hit the knuckle with a hammer.

Comment: @Ben Yep, I prefer the hammer approach myself, though I have used my gear puller for some of these as well. I just left a comment since I Nick C didn't mention the drawbacks of these types, and I didn't think it was worth a -1.