# Is WD40 a penetrant?

Tags: steering, lubrication

An outer tie rod is bound (screwed into) the inner tie rod as described [in this previous posting.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38113/outer-tie-rod-removal)

WD40 was sprayed at connection between the two tie rods and the jam nut was loosened.  Attempts to unscrew the outer rod were unsuccessful.  Is WD40 a good penetrant or is it merely a lubricant and I need to use another product?  I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I've always thought WD40 was a penetrant and *not* a lubricant. I was told never to use it in place of oil or grease. Maybe if WD40 isn't cutting it you could use heat?

Comment: Contact spray(for electronics) is a cheap and good oxidation remover. I regularly use it to unjam parts. You have give it a minute to do its work though.

Comment: I know this forum isn't for "shopping" but do yourself a favour, go buy some "PlusGas" releasing agent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and lesson-learned: always appreciated.  PlusGas does not seem to be available in United States: hopefully someone will prove this statement wrong?

Comment: Try getting some PB Blaster I think it's called?  Somewhere like Harbor Freight should stock it?

Comment: I think Harbor Freight carries it.  Most auto parts stores will carry it.  That's my go to.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.jalopyjournal.com/forum/threads/best-penetrating-oil-for-stuck-nuts-bolts.773380/

There was a study done on penetrating oils. Here's the highlights -

```
The break out torque required for:  
 Nothing = 516 ft. lbs.  
 WD-40 = 238 ft. lbs.  
 PB Blaster = 214 ft. lbs.  
 Liquid Wrench = 127 ft. lbs.  
 Kano Kroil = 106 ft. lbs.   
 50/50 blend of ATF and Acetone = 50 ft. lbs.
```

Answer (score 6):

WD40 is not a penetrant, and as far as lubricants go, it's a poor one. Get a legit penetrating oil at the car parts store. They come in spray cans and range from $7 to $15.

Answer (score 2):

WD40 is specifically designed to disperse water (hence WD). It is useful as a penetrant, lubricant and solvent and this versatility if one of the reasons why its is so popular and useful and versatile ie a can of WD40 in your tool box will do a lot of jobs reasonably well.

However there will also be more specialised products which perform specific functions better. For example in the case of a stuck tie rod you may be better off with a specialised penetrating oil.

Answer (score 1):

WD40's main use is actually as a water dispersant hence the WD, however it is also a anti-corrosion, penetrative lubricant and is excellent for helping free up seized nuts/bolts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just found WD-40 Penetrant.

[https://www.amazon.com/WD-40-Specialist-Release-Penetrant-Spray/dp/B0083V8JP6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0083V8JP6)